# Pygame Text Rectangles Overlapping

Tags: python, pygame

this is my code:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
window = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Draw')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
p1Img = pygame.image.load('player.png')
p2Img = pygame.image.load('player2.png')
bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
id = 1

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)






def player(x,y):
    window.blit(p1Img,(p1x,p1y))

def player2(x,y):
    window.blit(p2Img,(p2x,p2y))

def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()



def messageDisplay(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text,largeText)
    TextRect.center = (display_width/2, display_height/2)
    window.blit(TextSurf,TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def countDown(drawTime):
    while drawTime <= 5:
        time.sleep(1)
        pygame.display.update()
        messageDisplay(str(drawTime))
        drawTime += 1
    else:
        pygame.display.update()
        messageDisplay('Draw')



p1x = -5
p1y = 500
b1x = 56
b1y = 510

p2x = 740
p2y = 500
b2x = 740
b2y = 500

while(id != 0):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            id = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                window.blit(bullet,(b1x, b1y))
                pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                window.blit(bullet,(b1x, b1y))


    window.fill(white)
    player(p1x,p1y)
    player2(p2x,p2y)
    pygame.display.update()
    countDown(1)
    clock.tick(120)

pygame.quit()
```

The problem is that the text draws over itself. I've read countless things about how I need to redraw the surface but I'm not entirely sure what they mean? I did window.fill(white) but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: `time.sleep` and `while` in `countDown` is not good idea. It stops `mainloop`  and program will not response on keys for this time.

Answer (score 0):

You draw in `while` loop and you don't clear this place before you draw new text. You have to fill this place with background color or background image before you draw new text. Probably you could use `fill(white, TextRect)` to fill (clear) only part of screen.

You use `window.fill(white)` but not inside of `while` loop in `countDown` so it clears text (and all screen) after you finish counting.

`redraw` means "clear screen and draw everything again". To clear screen you use `fill(white)`

---

I don't know what you are trying to do - but `sleep` and `while` (in `countDown`) probably is not good idea.

Comment: I'm just trying to countdown before the game begins by going:
1
2
3
4
5
Draw
*Game begins* 
But the numbers are overlapping

Comment: you have to draw rectangle to "remove" old text before you draw new text. New text has no own background.